# C initialize struct in switch case

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement

So I have the following "shape" in my code:

```
mystruct t;
switch(something){
    case THIS:
        t = {/*initialization*/};
        break;
    case THAT:
        t = {/*initialization*/};
        break;           
    case AND_THE_OTHER:
        t = {/*initialization*/};
        break;
}
```

`gcc` insists that there should be an expression before the `{`:

```
error: expected expression before '{' token
    t = {
        ^
```

Why? What does `gcc` think I'm up to? What's the clean way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is assignment, not initialization.  Initialization can only be performed at the time the variable is defined.  Curly braces may be used to initialize a variable, but not to assign.

You'll need to assign each member of the struct individually.

Answer (score 3):

Use [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html#Compound-Literals):

```
t = (mystruct) { ... };
```

This is supported by C99+, but supported as an extension by GCC for C90.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have to work with C89. No convenience for me... :(

Comment: @HermanGhandi OK, that's unfortunate, but, if I may ask, why do you need to use C89? It's totally obsolete.

Comment: The university computers are like that. They can compile C99, but with flags that the graders may not use or like.